# how to hide a pager on xPage for xp:viewPanel?

Tags: css, xpages

When I make viewTable pager invisible it hides the pager itself but gray box is still shown. It doesn't happen for e.g. Data Table Control. Set background-color: xxx for viewTable control doesn't help. See attached picture. How to hide gray box for top pager?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this CSS to your XPage

```
.xspDataTableViewPanel > tbody > tr:first-of-type {
    display: none;
}
```

It will hide outer table's first row, which is the gray box on top.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Knut.. Well, that works but display:note; just hides that gray box. Sorry for unclear question but OK, I need to show it but set background white. So it's not shown as gray box either pager is visible or not visible. bgcolor=xxx background-color: xxx doesn't help

Comment: Change the classes `.xspDataTableViewPanelHeaderStart`, `.xspDataTableViewPanelHeaderMiddle` and `.xspDataTableViewPanelHeaderEnd` to white background color.